# Pigeonhole principle in Algorithm problems

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am reading Editorial about a problem on Codefoces but still not able to understand it beacuse as it is using PigeonHole principle , I am not getting how to apply pigeonhole priniciple on this problem

Here's problem Editorial:

In this problem we use the septimal number system. It is a very important limitation. Let's count how many digits are showed on the watch display and call it cnt. If cnt more than 7, the answer is clearly 0 (because of pigeonhole principle). If cnt is not greater than 7, then you can just bruteforces all cases.

Here' Problem Statement
http://codeforces.com/contest/686/problem/C

Robbers, who attacked the Gerda's cab, are very successful in covering from the kingdom police. To make the goal of catching them even harder, they use their own watches.

First, as they know that kingdom police is bad at math, robbers use the positional numeral system with base 7. Second, they divide one day in n hours, and each hour in m minutes. Personal watches of each robber are divided in two parts: first of them has the smallest possible number of places that is necessary to display any integer from 0 to n - 1, while the second has the smallest possible number of places that is necessary to display any integer from 0 to m - 1. Finally, if some value of hours or minutes can be displayed using less number of places in base 7 than this watches have, the required number of zeroes is added at the beginning of notation.

Note that to display number 0 section of the watches is required to have at least one place.

Little robber wants to know the number of moments of time (particular values of hours and minutes), such that all digits displayed on the watches are distinct. Help her calculate this number.

Comment: We are not a replacement for traditional learning. We aren't just going to conjure up some code from some other site for you.

Comment: The point of the pigeonhole principle here is simply to answer this kind of question: "Find a 8 digit number in which all the digits are different".  This task is obviously impossible as there are only 7 different digits allowed (0,1,2,3,4,5,6).

Answer (score 0):

The "Pigeonhole Principle" is just this:  if I try to put more than seven pigeons into seven pigeonholes, one of the holes has more than one pigeon in it.

Here, the septimal digits are the pigeonholes and the places in a time representation are the pigeons. So, if you can determine (quickly) for a given case that more than seven places would be needed to represent the time, the pigeonhole principle tells you there can be no representations having distinct digits, and you can skip the really slow work of counting such representations by brute-force and go on to the next case.